# How to set a specific resulting path for a file in the compiled jar?

Tags: java, maven

Lets say a example project structure

```
/src/java/main/com/example - the path to the base package
/src/java/resources/config.yml
```

I would want the config.yml to be in the base directory of the jar so it can get detected, but instead it gets compiled into `BOOT-INF/classes/`, so how would tell maven to put a file into a specific path?

Comment: So you are doing spring boot?

Comment: First why would you like to do that? If you are using spring-boot you should follow the conventions as well. And what kind of configuration does the `config.yml` represent?

Comment: Smart me decided to combine spring boot and spigot api, so it needs a plugin.yml in the base path of the jar to recognise it as a plugin
(excuse my english, nonnative here)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more in detail what you are doing... because it sounds the combination will not really work here...

Comment: So for a spigot plugin to function you need a plugin.yml in the base directory of the jar (when you open it in 7zip it should be there), but for some god forsaken reason when put in the resources folder it isnt placed in the root path but in /BOOT-INF/classes. So i was asking is there a way to force maven to put plugin.yml into the root of the jar

Comment: If you use it in relation with spring boot I'm not sure if this is really possible. The other question is why do this plugin needs having the `plugin.yml` in the root and when will the spigot plugin run? During build time?

Comment: When the server plugins it looks for the plugin.yml to recognise it as a plugin and to load configuration

Comment: And it gets run when its compiled and placed in the plugins folder of a spigot server setup

Comment: Are we talking about runtime or build time? If it's runtime that will not work if its build time you are applying it to the wrong artifact. In both cases a spring boot app is not a usual jar file...

Comment: After its build, yep guess thats runtime